# Is it possible to travel into / interact with NPCs in enemy faction territories?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

A friend and I want to venture into Daggerfall/Ebonheart territory, and ideally be able to do quests there. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While Bunyip's answer is basically correct, it isn't 100% complete:

You can't enter other alliances' territory through *Cyrodiil*.

The gates leading to their provinces (*High Rock*, *Morrowind*, and *Elsweyr*) are considered safe zones where players can spawn, organize etc. They're walled off (with one way doors back only usable by the owning alliance) and heavily guarded as well.

Once you've reached level 50 and completed your main quest storyline as well as your alliance's storyline, you'll be presented with the option to play one of the other remaining alliances as veteran content (often referred to as **50+**).

This will allow you to play all of that chosen alliance's content with your existing character while having everything upscaled to level 50 (so it's still challenging and you're not just breezing through heaps of low level enemies).

Once you've finished your second alliance playthrough as well, you'll be presented with the option to play the last remaining alliance's content as **50++** which will once again allow you to enjoy the content with raised level/difficulty to accomodate your more experienced character.

As a side note: I haven't heard of any rumors changing this, simply because of the fact that it wouldn't fit well with the storylines (and the content is accessible already). Take the *Ebonheart Pact* storyline as an example. Without spoiling anything significant, it starts off with an invasion of *Daggerfall Covenant* forces in Skyrim and Morrowind. Why would they allow any member of the *Daggerfall Covenant* to join their ranks driving them back? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: (switches best answer) :3

But a question -- does this mean at 50+ you can LITERALLY be in another factions territory in the real world, with other players seeing you there? Can they not attack you and vice versa in such circumstances? i.e. is this "Playthrough" the same as what they experience on the other faction?

Comment: No, consider all zones existing at least three times (due to how phasing/layering works, there'll be even more copies). So, for example, everyone from *Ebonheart Pact* who starts the *Aldmeri Dominion* story will still play with other players from the *Ebonheart Pact* in higher-level copies of the same zones *Aldmeri Dominion* players experience immediately.

Comment: Everquest 2 let you change faction by way of a long and difficult "Betrayal" quest line, that did make a lot of sense lore wise (you were basically betraying your allegiance, and there was a phase where as a result neither side trusted you until you had proven yourself not to be a nasty double agent).

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you are only allowed to stay in your own faction's zone (with the exception or Cyrodiil, which is a huge battleground). You cannot enter into or interact with NPC's in other factions' territories.

Comment: which is very disappointing

Comment: @khanahk Many players agree, and there is rumor that they might be changing this.

Comment: @khanahk If you're really particular about this answer/topic, then this answer is not correct. You can't get to the other territories immediately, but in the end you're indeed able to do so.

Answer (score -2):

Well apparently you can now.  I know this reply is old... but I'm Daggerfall Covenant and accidentally found my way into an obvious Ebonpact land.  Strangely, the Daggerfall soldiers in that land are all red to me and will attack me now so I guess there is not really any faction in the usual meaning of the term.

Comment: Is this meant to address the accepted answer?